# Warning: validateDOMNesting(...): <h1> cannot appear as a child of <h2> except it doesn't

Tags: reactjs

The elements appear to be nested correctly, yet the invalid nesting error persists. What gives? Other answers seemed to be pointing out a real nesting error...

```js
  const screens = [
    <Fragment key='input1'>
      <h1>Screen Heading 1</h1>
      <h2>Sub-Heading 1</h2>
      <input
        type='text'
        id='input1'
        onChange={onChange}
        value={contentData.input1}
      />
    </Fragment>,
    <Fragment key='input2'>
      <h1>Screen Heading 2</h1>
      <h2>Sub-Heading 2</h2>
      <input
        type='text'
        id='input2'
        onChange={onChange}
        value={contentData.input2}
      />
    </Fragment>,
    <Fragment key='input3'>
      <h1>Screen Heading 3</h1>
      <h2>Sub-Heading 3</h2>
      <input
        type='text'
        id='input3'
        onChange={onChange}
        value={contentData.input3}
      />
    </Fragment>
  ]
```

Comment: could you provide a sandbox? I wasn't able to reproduce your error

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I figured it out. The fragments were rendering in an h2. This error message is verified trustworthy. :)

Comment: But The fragments were rendering in an h1 also, so how does it justify that?pls explain